# MFC CFindReplaceDialog destruction

Tags: windows, mfc

How can I destroy a pointer to `CFindReplaceDialog` object properly?

For example I have class:

```
class CjumpView : public CRichEditView
{
   CFindReplceDialog *m_pFRDlg;
   // ...
}; 

CjumpView::CjumpView()
            : m_pFRDlg(NULL)
{

}

CjumpView::~CjumpView()
{
   if(m_pFRDlg != NULL)
   {
      m_pFRDlg->DestroyWindow();
      delete(m_pFRDlg);
   }
}

void CjumpView::OnEditFind()
{
    if(m_pFRDlg == NULL)
    {
        const bool fShowFind = true;
        m_pFRDlg = new CFindReplaceDialog();
        m_pFRDlg->Create(fShowFind, m_sFind, NULL, NULL, this)
    }

}


LRESULT CjumpView::OnFind(WPARAM, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPFINDREPLACE lpFindReplace = reinterpret_cast<LPFINDREPLACE>(lParam);
    if(lpFindReplace->Flags & FR_DIALOGTERM)
    {
        m_pFRDlg->DestroyWindow();
            delete(m_pFRDlg);
            m_pFRDlg = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    lpFindReplace->Flags = 0;
    return NULL;
}
```

In Visual Studio `CFindReplaceDialog` help article it is said that objects of this class should be created in heap using `new` operator. Then `Create` member function should be called.

My `OnFind` function reacts on closing of this Find dialog. It calls `DestroyWindow()` function, the tries to delete dialog object.

But when I try to call `DestoyWindow()` in `OnFind()` or in destructor I have an exception:

> Access violation at address...

How to destroy this dialog and to delete pointer?

Answer (score 2):

If someone's interested as me on this problem, the solution is simple.
Actually you don't have to delete `CFindReplaceDislog*` pointer after it has been used.

After it's closed, it receives `WM_NCDESTROY` message. And as far as it's derived from `CWnd`, `CWnd::OnNcDestroy()` handler is invoked. In the last line it calls `PostNcDestroy()` which does nothing in `CWnd`, but overriden in `CFindReplaceDialog`. There it deletes 'this' pointer like so:

```
void CFindReplaceDialog::PostNcDestroy()
{
    ASSERT(m_hWnd == NULL);
    delete this;
}
```

So, you don't have to invoke `delete(m_pFRDlg)` anywhere.